# Having issue in using zustand to keep state updated

Tags: reactjs, zustand

I am new to zustand and currently experienceing to build state by it.

In my app I have two component; one is parent, another one is child, which is wrapped by parent.

I have tried different way to create state in child. The result, however, is not as expected as the created state could not be updated in child.

Why is that?

App.js:

```
    import "./styles.css";
    import useCounterStore from "./hooks/useCounterStore";
    import Child from "./Child";
    export default function App() {
      const { count, add } = useCounterStore();
      return 

(
    <div>
      Parent
      <div className="childContainer">
        <Child name="child1"></Child>
        <Child name="child2"></Child>
      </div>
      <p>{count}</p>
      <button onClick={add}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Child.js:

```
import create from "zustand";
export default function Child(props) {
  const { name } = props;

  const { count, add } = create((set) => ({
    count: 1,
    add: () => set((state) => ({ count: state.count + 1 }))
  }))();

  return (
    <div className="child">
      <p>{name}</p>
      <p>{count}</p>
      <button onClick={add}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

useCounterStore.js

```
 import create from "zustand";

const useCounterStore = create((set) => ({
  count: 1,
  add: () => set((state) => ({ count: state.count + 1 }))
}));

export default useCounterStore;
```

Child count always stay at 1

[image]

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding the usage of Zustand. Zustand provides global state management.  You don't want to create a store at the component level. `useCounterStore` would be used to create values such as `Child1count` and `Child2count` . This is so that the state is persistent. Then each child component can use that state regardless of re render. It feels like in your example, you're just wanting to create a custom hook that tracks the count regardless of how many child components there are.

Comment: Exactly, actually I deliberately to build zustand by like creating custom hook. ( create a hook at the component level, in this case it is Child.  But why did it work as expected when I click add while it works as expected as I clicked the add in parent @RyanZeelie

Comment: If you're creating the store at the component level, it's going to get re created every time state changes and the component re renders.. Thus resetting it . Whereas your parent is using the external store. So that maintains it's state as expected (Zustand doing its job) .

Comment: wait.... i also created the store within parent as well ; const { count, add } = useCounterStore();  which also run the create function. Why isnt to re create the state everytime @RyanZeelie?

Comment: That was my point :) You're misunderstanding how Zustand works. You're not creating the store in the parent. You're accessing the store in the parent. The store is being created at runtime of your app.

Comment: why is that when I use useCounterStore() in parent, then it means I am only accessing the store, while in child, it means creating the store.  I mean both were actutally run create function. Sorry if this sounds to trivial to explain.... @RyanZeelie

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250808/discussion-between-ryan-zeelie-and-ae-leung).

Comment: Not sure if you are able to see updated in group chat. Just a remind as I dont see there is a notification for me when there is a update on group chat, in case you've seen it. meanwhile, have a good day @RyanZeelie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a answer from @RyanZeelie. It is worth posting it.

useCounterStore() means you're calling the store that was created at app runtime. App starts, zustand creates the store. Your app loads. Now the store is created and can be accessed on any page by calling useCounterStore(). This is not going to create the store every time. It's already created. Calling create() at the component level is going to create a new store but since you're creating it in a component. Every time that component re renders

Whenever a component re renders, you're not re rendering the entire app. Only specific components . So you're re rendering the child, and it's re creating all the functions in the child component, thus throwing out the store that was made at that level and creating it again.